# ISupportIncrementalLoading doesn't stop after navigating away

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, infinite-scroll

I suddenly found a strange behavior of collection implementing ISupportIncrementalLoading. 
Let's say we have a main page with ISupportIncrementalLoading collection bound to ListView. And we have another page where we can navigate to.
When navigating to main page, the ISupportIncrementalLoading starts loading items until ListView thinks it's enough. I navigate to new page BEFORE ListView loaded all items it needs.
My expected behavior: ListView stops loading new items as the page isn't visible now.
Real behavior: ListView continues to load items endlessly, even after going away from the page. And it won't stop until gets HasMore == false.
Can anyone help with this? This is absolutely wrong behavior.

PS

If I while navigation, set in ViewModel the collection to null and then restore it when coming back -- it seams to help, but that is too much to do, I think.

Here's the code of my basic ISupportIncrementalLoading collection:

```
public abstract class BaseIncrementalSupportCollection<T> :IList<T>,IList,INotifyCollectionChanged, ISupportIncrementalLoading, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected readonly List<T> storage;

    private bool isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return isLoading;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isLoading != value)
            {
                isLoading = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool failed;

    public bool IsFailed
    {
        get { return failed; }
        set
        {
            if (failed != value)
            {
                failed = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get { return !HasMoreItems && Count == 0; }
    }

    protected BaseIncrementalSupportCollection()
    {
        storage = new List<T>();
    }

    public virtual IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        return Task.Run(()=>LoadMoreItems(count)).AsAsyncOperation();
    }

    public abstract bool HasMoreItems { get; }


    private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItems(uint count)
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        IsFailed = false;
        try
        {
            var items = await LoadMoreItemsOverride(count);
            if (items == null)
                return new LoadMoreItemsResult() {Count = 0};
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                var prevEmptyState = IsEmpty;
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var currItem = item;
                    await DispatchHelper.RunOnUiIfNecessary(async () =>
                    {
                        storage.Add(currItem);
                        RaiseCollectionChanged(
                            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, currItem,
                                storage.Count - 1));
                    });
                }
                if(prevEmptyState!=IsEmpty)
                    RaisePropertyChanged("IsEmpty");

            }
            return new LoadMoreItemsResult() {Count = (uint) items.Count};
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var aggregate = e as AggregateException;
            if (aggregate != null)
                e = aggregate.Flatten().InnerException;
            IsFailed = true;
            var handler = OnError;
            if (handler != null)
                DispatchHelper.RunOnUiIfNecessary(
                    () => handler(this, new IncrementallCollectionLoadErrorEventArgs(e)));
            return new LoadMoreItemsResult() {Count = 0};
        }
        finally
        {
            IsLoading = false;
        }

    }

    protected virtual void RaiseCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }

    protected abstract Task<IList<T>> LoadMoreItemsOverride(uint count);

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            DispatchHelper.RunOnUiIfNecessary(()=>handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler<IncrementallCollectionLoadErrorEventArgs> OnError;
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found another way, adding additional bool field isStopped with methods Start, ForceStop setting it to false/true. This value is used when getting HasMoreItems like

bool HasMoreItems{get{return !isStopped && DetermineIfHasMore()};}

And simply by calling those to methods I can stop or continue loading the same collection generator.

Another way is provided here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/be17357d-faac-4f49-acf4-e916fcdace9d/w81isupportincrementalloading-doesnt-stop-after-navigating-away?forum=winappswithcsharp